# Undefined method permit for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm currently designing and implementing a RoR API.

I'm facing an issue concerning strong parameters.

I'm expecting to receive the following attributes:

```
{ analysis_data: { barcode: "some_string" } }
```

To ensure that, I simply use the require/permit combination:

```
params.require(:analysis_data).permit(:barcode)
```

This works well if analysis data is nil or an hash.

However, if the client submit a request where analysis_data is a string instead of an hash, the request returns an error 500.

For example:

```
 { analysis_data: "some_string" }
```

Produces the following 500 error:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "barcode":String):
```

Is there any `clean` workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
params.fetch(:analysis_data, {}).permit(:barcode)
```

Comment: Thought it would solve the problem when I first read it this morning. But I've tried and after testing it it's not working. It is still fetching the string and try to  call permit on that string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to permit the string and hash or prevent the string without throwing the error. If it's the former you can use `params.require(:analysis_data).permit!` to allow any value as long as it's inside of analysis_data.

Comment: No, it's about the second one: prevent the string to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
params[:analysis_data].is_a?(ActionController::Parameters) ? params.fetch(:analysis_data, {}).permit(:barcode) : {}
```

or more readable like this:

```
return {} unless params[:analysis_data].is_a? ActionController::Parameters
params.fetch(:analysis_data, {}).permit(:barcode)
```

That way, `.permit` will only be called if a `ActionController::Parameters` is submitted, and otherwise return an empty hash.